# Android unzip password protected file from assets

Tags: android, zip, password-protection

I have password protected zip file from **assets** folder. Android zip library doesn't support password protected file so I was use **zip4j** library. But I cant extract file from assets.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("file:///android_asset/db.zip");
zipFile.setPassword("qwe");
```

Comment: what errors are you facing??

Comment: I get an error FileNotFoundException

Answer (score -1):

`file:///android_asset` is pretty much just for `WebView`.

If zip4j has a `ZipFile` constructor that takes an `InputStream`, you could get a stream on your asset via `getAssets().open("db.zip")`.

Otherwise, you would first need to copy `db.zip` from assets to a local file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), then use zip4j, then delete the local `db.zip` file.

Or, since cracking the encryption on a ZIP archive is trivial (last I checked), unZIP the contents into your project's `assets/` directory and use them more directly, rather than putting the password-protected ZIP into `assets/`.